# Multiple viewports and text in OpenGL...maybe it's the camera?

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, viewport

I have to have an OpenGL program working with two viewports. In one of them I have to have a model of a helicopter with a working camera that rotates around it every which way. Before I decided to get the viewport split going I got the camera working on the model as it was higher priority. The other viewport is supposed to show the FPS counter, but for some reason I can only see the text from specific angles.

My code follows:

```
    //sets up the viewports
    void setView(int option)
    {
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();

        switch (option)
        {
            case 1: 
                glViewport(0,height-150,width,150);
                break;
            case 2:
                glViewport(0,0,width,height-150);
                break;
        }
        if(persp)
            gluPerspective(fovy, (GLfloat) width /(GLfloat) height , near, far);
        else
            glOrtho(left,right,bottom,top,-10,10);  

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        myCam.updateLook();
    }

    void writeBitmapString(void *font, char *string)
    {  
       char *c;
       for (c = string; *c != '\0'; c++) glutBitmapCharacter(font, *c);
    } 

    //main draw function
    void display(void)
    {   
        //Text portion of the window
        setView(1);
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glRasterPos3f(0, 0, 0.0);
        writeBitmapString((void*)font, "Test text");
        glutSwapBuffers();

        //Viewport for heli
        setView(2);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);                
        glPushMatrix();
    //....The rest is just the modelling stuff
    glPopMatrix(); // final pop clause
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does myCam.updateLook() do?

Comment: It calls the gluLookAt function and sets the look at point to the centre of the chopper. It also handles all new positioning for the camera. The position of the camera is modified by the IJKL keys.

Comment: @Galipan: You fell for the one tutorial SNAFU people tend to make again and again: Setting up projection and viewport outside the rendering function. Move that code into the drawing code and things become obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really sounds like you want a HUD here (forgive me for double guessing your intentions). Render your scene, then do a glLoadIdentity on both the modelview & projection matrices. Then load your glOrtho. Finally, set your raster positions for your text and render.